# How to deploy rails application to amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to amazon servcies, currently, i have an rails application and ready to deploy to amazon ec2, and connect to amazon rds.

But I am not sure which way is the most straightforward to deploy application to amazon ec2 and connect to rds.

I did some research on amazon documentation, seems there are several ways to do that:

1. [CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-deploy-revision.html)
2. [ElasticBeansTalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)
3. OpsWork

Moreover, rubber seems another way to deploy rails application. 
But those methods made me confused, which one is the most simplest one.

Could someone guide me how to deploy rails application to amazon ec2 and connect to rds database service?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Check [Overview of Deployment Options on AWS](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/overview-of-deployment-options-on-aws.pdf) whitepaper for comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is Elasticbeanstalk: it is aimed at being PaaS very similar to heroku with quick to deploy time. We've had great success with this although you need to ensure your app supports Puma or the other webservers they provide. Adoption is quick.

Opsworks is a solid choice and there are papers/blog posts on how.

CodeDeploy is newer and might be tougher to find information that is ready for clicking through to get an app.

In the end it's based on opinion, but if you just need a Rails Application and an RDS database, that is precisely what Beanstalk attempts to make simple.